# Unable to create a model with Eloquent create method. Error telling MassAssignMentException

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have created a model named, Author. I tried creating a model with the help of eloquent create method like this:

```
public function postCreate(){
   Author::create(array(
       'user' => Input::get('user'),
       'info' => Input::get('info') 
   ));
   return Redirect::to('authors')
        ->with('message', 'User created successfully');
}
```

'user' and 'info' are the name of the form elements. I am sure I am not mistaken with typo. When I run this, models is not created and says MassAssignmentException.

But when I tried with the following method, the model is created and was saved in the table

```
public function postCreate(){

    $author = new Author;
    $author->name = Input::get('user');
    $author->info= Input::get('info');
    $author->save();

    return Redirect::to('authors')
        ->with('message', 'User created successfully');

}
```

And I really want to use the create method, its just looks much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Are there "user" & "info" field or "user" & "bio" fields in the Author model?

Comment: @fideloper my bad, it's 'user' and 'info' .. I have corrected it, thnx for pointing out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this should work for you:

1) as already listed by @fideloper and @the-shift-exchange, in your Author model you need to create the below field (this is a white-list of all database columns you want to be available for autopopulation [mass assignment] )

```
 protected $fillable = array('user','info', ... ,'someotherfield');
```

2) use the below code to fire the mass asssignment mechanism

```
$author = new Author;
$author->fill(Input::all());
$author->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the  MassAssignmentException when I have extends my model like this.

```
class Author extends Eloquent {

}
```

I was trying to insert array like this

```
Author::create($array);//$array was data to insert.
```

**Issue has been resolve** when I created Author Model as given below.

```
class Author extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();  // Important
}
```

Reference https://github.com/aidkit/aidkit/issues/2#issuecomment-21055670

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [Mass Assignment fields](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment). In your Author model:

class Author extends Eloquent {

```
protected $fillable = array('name', 'bio');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your model needs to have the $fillable variable set.

See the documentation on [mass-assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment) for details.

It will look something like this in your Author model:

```
protected $fillable = array('user', 'info');
```

Comment: still the same error, MassAssignMentException. By the way I read the documentation on Mass assignment. But it didnt help me a lot. sorry to be a pain but what do this mean: 'mass-assignable' ...

Comment: that means that the attributes you list in $fillable are massassign-enabled = you can autopopulate them with that mechanism.

Comment: You can't use `create()` for `fill()` methods without defining which fields are "mass-assignable" in the "fillable" array. Conversely, there's also a [guarded array](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L119).

Comment: Now it's working, it was a silly mistake from my side. I added this property in controller which was a blunder, when added to model, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `protected $fillable` property by assigning it an array of fields/columns which you want to fill/assign values to. For example you have a model with fields `f1, f2, f3 and f4`. You want to assign values to `f1, f2 and f3 but not to f4` then you need to use:

```
protected $fillable = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3'];
```

The above line would allow to pass an array to the:

```
$mod = Model::create($arr);
$mod->save();
```

Whatever the $arr array contains, but only `f1, f2, and f3` will be assigned values (if values exists in the `$arr array for f1, f2, f3`).

Hope it will help you and others.